# sql server delete statement in Jmeter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to delete some records from SQL server database but I got the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

and here is my statement:

```
DELETE FROM POS_SOF_TEST.dbo.TERMINALS
```

Comment: Error looks like an Oracle one. Are you sure you are using SQL Server?

Comment: it seems you may be missing `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle (I believe so, from the error message) you need to end each and every SQL statement by ;